# Does Internet Explorer's Enterprise Mode ignore X-UA-Compatible IE=edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a web application that was created for a large multinational client, targeting IE9 as the lowest supported browser. Unfortunately, part of their organization has Windows 7 machines with IE9 where IT has imposed IE7 Enterprise Mode.

We have tried to override this by setting a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` tag but this seems to be ignored.

At this point I assume that Enterprise Mode will override any compatibility set by meta tag or HTTP response header, but I have not been able to find any documentation on MSDN, confirming or contradicting this.

At this point, I am just hoping to point to some documentation so the client can see that unless our site has specific settings for compatibility set by their IT, there is not anything else that we can do.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A couple of documents suggest that the later document modes might still be available.  The [Standards Support docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243496(v=vs.85).aspx)  provide a flowchart that suggests this and this "[no time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/notime/2015/04/11/ie-enterprise-mode-in-a-nutshell/)" document (which is sort of hard to parse) describes the interplay of various factors.  You may also be fighting GPOs, CVL, and other customizations.

Comment: Thanks @LanceLeonard! That "no time" link you shared is very helpful. Specifically in the Overview section where it states "Has priority over Compatibility View List and X-UA-Compatible meta tag.".

This to me means that the X-UA-Compatible meta tag can be trounced if IE7 Enterprise Mode is in effect.